# Running ajax on page load and then every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I still find it hard to grasp some of the javascript/jquery concepts.

I wanted to find a way of loading ajax on page load and then every 10 seconds after that. I stumbled upon http://www.erichynds.com/blog/a-recursive-settimeout-pattern which suggested is a good idea as it provided some error detection to stop script running if ajax fails, only problem is that on page load, it must wait 5 seconds before requesting data, I want it to request data every 10 seconds, as well as on page load, so I don't have to wait 10 seconds before seeing anything.

How do I get it to load on page load aswel as every 10 seconds after that?

I tried adding the following:

```
   if(this.success_count&&this.failed == 0)
    {
        jQuery.proxy(this.getData, this)
    }else{
        setTimeout(
           jQuery.proxy(this.getData, this),
           this.interval
        );
    }
```

To this:

```
    var poller = {

        failed: 0,
        success_count: 0,

        interval: 10000,

        init: function(){

           if(this.success_count&&this.failed == 0)
            {
                jQuery.proxy(this.getData, this)
            }else{
                setTimeout(
                   jQuery.proxy(this.getData, this),
                   this.interval
                );
            }
         },

       getData: function(){
           var self = this;

           jQuery.ajax({
               url        : "foo.htm",
               success    : jQuery.proxy(self.successHandler, self),
               error    : jQuery.proxy(self.errorHandler, self)
           });
       },

        // => Handle Success
        successHandler : function( response ){

              if( response === "failure" ){
                  this.errorHandler();
              } else {
                ++this.success_count;
                  this.init();
              }
          },

       errorHandler: function(){
           if( ++this.failed < 5 ){
              this.interval += 1000;
              this.init();
           }
       }
    };

poller.init();
```

I then also tried this, but it requests the data twice, understandably once for each.

```
poller.getData();
poller.init();
```

Comment: Init should be 1st i guess

Comment: Why don't you call `getData()` in your `init()` before starting your `setTimeout`?

Comment: Antoine, I tried adding getData(), this.getData; at the beginning before timeout and it still wouldn't work

Comment: Can you explain what the point of your `if` statement in your `init()` function is ? Also, how did it not work ? Did you get an error message ? Where did you try to call `getData()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a document ready function using jquery to fire it off at the beginning of the page load and then also have a setTimeout function that calls the ajax call every 10 seconds. See below for an example.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        ajaxFunctionCall();
        setTimeout( ajaxFunctionCall, 10000 );
   });
```

Comment: Hi Keith, this was the way I originally thought about doing, but after reading that link, apparantly the code you presented would mean if there are errors on loading the ajax, the above code ignores it and continues forever trying to load a dead page. The code on the link meant you can stop processing the error and display a custom failure message. That was my understanding i have not mis understood it

Answer (score 0):

call the function on load, clear it and add settimeout inside the function

```js
var tr=null;
$(function(){
  
  tr=setTimeout(function(){timerFunction();},100);
  
  });

function timerFunction(){
  
  clearTimeout(tr);
  
  //insert following after success
  tr=setTimeout(function(){timerFunction();},10000);
  
  }
```